# What are the features of English diphthongs?

Tags: english, phonemes, diphthongs

Do diphthongs adopt all the features of their components? For example, ɔɪ consists of ɔ (sonorant, continuant, approximant, voice, round, back, syllabic) and ɪ (sonorant, continuant, approximant, voice, high, front, syllabic). So is ɔɪ *all* of those (sonorant, continuant, approximant, voice, round, high, back, front, syllabic)?

And if this is the case, how are the features of diphthongs determined from their component phonemes?

Comment: The first part has some features and the second part has some other features, but mostly they're the same. So you have a split of features indicating a change in articulation, which is what diphthongs are.